# proof $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n) \to \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \to \infty$ $\lor$ $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Tried to prove the above-mentioned statement, however got stuck in one case.

In case $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \to \infty$ then it's proved.

In case $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \not\to \infty$ it can be $\to K$ for specific K or to $-\infty$
so by the arithmetic laws of limits if it's K+$\infty$ then it tends to $\infty$ as needed.

However, in the case when $a_n \to -\infty$, I have no clue how to prove the truth of $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n \to \infty$.

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is false, so you cannot prove it.

Counterexample:

$$a_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 1 & n \mbox{ odd} \\ n & n \mbox{ even} \end{matrix} \right. \ \ \
b_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix} n & n \mbox{ odd} \\ 1 & n \mbox{ even} \end{matrix} \right.$$

What is true is that either $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n = \infty$ or $\limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n = \infty$.

Comment: I think what OP might have meant, is given that all the limits exist.